# Integral over asteroid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate $$\int_L\frac{x^2dy-y^2dx}{x^{5/3}+y^{5/3}}$$ where $L=\{x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=R^{2/3}\}$ (and L is part of an asteroid as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=R\cos^3{t}$ and $y=R\sin^3{t}$.  If $L$ is the part of the curve in the first quadrant, then the integral is

$$3 R^{4/3} \int_0^{\pi/2} dt \, \frac{\cos^7{t} \sin^2{t} + \sin^7{t} \cos^2{t}}{\cos^5{t}+\sin^5{t}} = \frac{3}{4} R^{4/3} \int_0^{\pi/2} dt \, \sin^2{2 t} = \frac{3 \pi}{16} R^{4/3}$$

Comment: Cool, this is what I got too. Thank you.